# Ubercart - Manual Credit Card Processing

Tags: ubercart

This has ALWAYS been the reason why I haven't used Ubercart...the lack of a module that allows for offline (manual) credit card information.

It has been a few years now since I looked last and I am wondering if this is STILL not an option with Ubercart. I did some searches and it still looks like there is nothing.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is more of a workflow question than, a lack of module(s) question.    You can setup Ubercart so that you accept an order without accepting a payment.   You can set the status of the order as non-processed.   You then process their payment manually (via phone, online, inperson, etc), then, manually, change the status of their order to process.

Comment: I was wanting the customer to be able to enter the CC information during the checkout stage, and then run their credit card information manually using my terminal. Is this possible?

Comment: Ubercart does not store Credit Card information to maintain PCI compliance (Payment Card Industry)